# Localize DatePicker / DateTimePicker

Tags: codenameone

I use a DateTime Picker in an editor of my app (within a PickerComponent). I'm using it only in lightweight mode, since DateTime Picker fail on Android if not (not tested since some months, but I suppose it still the case).

I've successfully translated the buttons "Cancel" and "Done" with the L10N API, but I can't translate months (for Date type) or abbreviated day/month (for DateTime).

The keys for each months are putted in the .res file, that worked for the buttons, but it does not work for the months of the picker.

Any hint on how to achieve this localization ? Some of our customer are really bad at english... Thanks in advance !

Comment: [localise datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i18n.html) try this from bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, but that's Javascript, not CodenameOne, so it can't work on a CodenameOne app (except maybe for the Javascript build, but I don't use it at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is localized via `SimpleDateFormat` and its class `DateFormatSymbols`. Unfortunately this has no way to globally customize that value using the standard project resource bundle which seems to be a serious omission of that code. This is something we'll need to fix via the issue tracker, I don't see a short term workaround from a brief glance at the code as it assumes you would have access to the `SimpleDateFormat` which is highly impractical.